# javascript object key and value as array

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

i want to create an object dynamically of the form - {"abc": [x1,x2], "efg": [x3, x4, x1]}
The following code is not working.. what's the problem here ?

```
var catCmp = {};
var x1="abc";
var x2="efg";

var y1="x1";
var y2="x2";
var y3="x3";
var y4="x4";

if (typeof catCmp[x1] === 'undefined') {
    catCmp[x1] = [];
}
if (typeof catCmp[x2] === 'undefined') {
    catCmp[x2] = [];
}

catCmp[x1] = catCmp[x1].push(y1);
catCmp[x1] = catCmp[x1].push(y2);
catCmp[x2] = catCmp[x2].push(y3);
catCmp[x2] = catCmp[x2].push(y4);
catCmp[x2] = catCmp[x2].push(y1);

console.log('catCmp :::', catCmp);
```

Comment: Why are you doing this `catCmp[x1] = catCmp[x1].push(y1);` instead of `catCmp[x1].push(y1);` ?

Comment: thanks for all the pointers, especially "push method returns length of new object"..

Answer (score 6):

You need not assign back the result of the push operation. You can simply call `catCmp[x1].push(y1);`

Comment: not just you need not, actually you should not, because push method returns length of new object.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't. I was just saying it in a nice way! :-)

Answer (score 3):

In the line:

```
catCmp[x1] = catCmp[x1].push(y1);
```

the value returned by `catCmp[x1].push(y1)` is the value of `y1`. So that is the value assigned to `catCmp[x1]`.

As suggested in other answers, don't do the assignment, just do:

```
catCmp[x1].push(y1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
catCmp[x1].push(y1);
catCmp[x1].push(y2);
catCmp[x2].push(y3);
catCmp[x2].push(y4);
catCmp[x2].push(y1);
```

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript push method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the object upon which push method is called.

So, in your case, the statement

```
catCmp[x1] = catCmp[x1].push(y1);
```

makes catCmp[x1] = catCmp[x1].length

Not just you need not, you should not assign back the result of push operation. So, just use:

```
catCmp[x1].push(y1);
```